# How is the "static" keyword affecting the calculation?

Tags: c, recursion, static

I have an issue in this code, using the `static` keyword. Here, after n = 3, I thought the value of `r` will be 5, but I found out that the value of `r` is 50! I don't know how `static` works here:

```
int magic(int n)
{
    static int r = 5;
    if (n <= 0) return 10;

    if (n > 3)
    {
        r = 50;
        return(r + magic(n-1));
    }
    return(r - magic(n-1));
}

int main()
{
    int x;
    x = magic(8);
    printf("%d",x);
}
```

Here output is 290, because `r` has a value of 50 in all cases. Please can someone help me in this.

Comment: Look up the keyword `static` as it relates to the C language. It doesn't mean a "constant" if that's what you were thinking.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/storage_duration

Comment: The function name is inappropriate.  There is nothing magic about this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572547/what-does-static-mean-in-c

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c/info

Comment: Are you sure about the line `if(r>3)`? Maybe it should be`if(r>5)`??

Comment: Actually, the code as entered gives 410! In order to get 290 (as you claim), I need to change the line to: `if (n>3)`. Please ensure the code you five us is the code you are working with!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have the statement, `static int r = 5;`, this signals to the compiler that the variable `r` will be initialised to the value `5` ***at compile time***. That means, it will ***not*** be reset to `5` each time the function is called!

Also, the line `if (r > 3)` doesn't work as you suggest (see my comment in your question)! Changing to `if (n > 3)` does what you say.

Anyway, the following code does something different (outputs 245), but I'm not sure what you expect the output to be:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int magic(int n)
{
    int r = 5; // NOT STATIC - so this is reset to 5 at the start of each call!
    if (n <= 0) return 10;
    else if (n > 3) { // Your "if (r > 3)" means the block will ALWAYS execute!
        r = 50;
        return(r + magic(n - 1));
    }
    return(r - magic(n - 1));
}
```

**EDIT:** I shall try to add some clarification! Consider a statement that declares and initialises a static variable in the 'global' scope (that is, not inside any function, or even in `main`):

```
static int StatInt1 = 42;
```

When the compiler encounters this statement, it 'allocates' a part of memory for the program, large enough to hold an `int` and gives that piece of memory the value that represents `42`. The compiler **does not** generate any machine code instruction for moving the value given into that memory; in fact, it ***cannot possibly*** generate such code - for there is no 'context' in which to run that code.

However, if you later (somewhere in a function, or in `main`) have a statement like this:

```
StatInt1 = 9;
```

then the compiler **will** generate code that moves the representation of the value `9` into the memory previously 'allocated' for the variable. Exactly what this code will be depends on the compiler and target machine, but let's say it is an instruction `MOVE 9 TO @StatInt1` (where @StatInt1 is the address of the 'allocated' memory block).

Now, if you were to move the `static int StatInt1 = 42;` statement into the body of a function (much like you have), this (by definition) does not change the way the compiler interprets the statement! All it does is make access to the variable 'local' to that function. *There is still no code generated to move the value into the variable!*

But a variable inside a function that is ***not*** declared static is treated very differently - we sometimes refer to such variables as 'automatic'! The memory block for such a variable is only 'allocated' when the function is actually invoked, and then it will be assigned the value given in the initialiser **each time** the function is called. (Typically, most compilers will create the memory on the stack: short-term memory that is 'wiped out' when the function ends.)

In your code, the `static int r = 5;` does not generate any code, so there is no 'automatic' re-assignment of the value `5` when the function is called. Thus, once the function has been called in such a way as to assign the value `50` to `r`, it will keep that value until you **explicitly** give it another value.

I apologise if this is rambling - but I hope it makes it clear(er) what is going on!

Comment: Yes you are right about "if (n>3)", it was a typing mistake. I get that how if we doesn't use "static" then we get the output 245. But I am confused how we get output 290 when we use static. How in the last cases when (n <= 3) we didn't run the "if statement" still we get r = 50. How?

Comment: Because the variable is declared as `static`, it will keep any value it's assigned until it is given another one. However, the value assigned in the **initialisation** doesn't count as one of these 'until' cases if it is declared `static` - it will ***only*** be initialised once (at compile time). So, with your code, once the `if` block has been executed once, the value will be unchanged - unless, of course, you add an `else` block where it is reset to its 'original' value.

Comment: @AkshatJain It may be clearer if you consider what would happen if you had `static int r = 5;` ***outside*** any function (i.e. as a global variable)! This would have much the same effect - except that you would then be able to 'see' the variable from anywhere (not just inside the function). Does this help?

Comment: Thank you so much Adrian for this explanation!!! Now I get the concept.